# Fixed Sidebar - Smooth Scrolling in another Div

Tags: jquery, css, html

When anchor tag is clicked on sidebar, the page has to scroll down to content. I am getting the right offset to scrollTop but its not scrolling down.How to fix this scrolling issue

My HTML - includes a fixed sidebar

```
 <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav" id="sidebar">
      <li class="sidebar-brand"><a id="menu-toggle" href="#">Menu<i class="fa fa2 fa-align-justify"></i></a></li>
      <li><a  href="">Home<i class="fa fa-home "></i></a></li>
      <li><a  href="#about">About<i class="fa fa-beer"></i></a></li>
      <li><a   href="#resume">Resume<i class="fa fa-rocket"></i></span></a></li>
      <li><a  href="#work">Work<i class="fa fa-headphones"></i></a></li>
      <li><a  href="#contact">Contact<i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>


 <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="page-content inset">
      <!-- Home Page -->
      <div class="row container-full" id="home">      

      </div>
      <!-- Home Page End -->
      <!-- About Page -->
      <div class="row container-full" id="about">
```

My CSS

```
html,body{
 height:100%;
 overflow:auto; // For chrome rendering
 }

 #wrapper {
padding-left: 70px; // For toggling effect
transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
height: 100%;
  }

#sidebar-wrapper {
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  margin-left: -150px;
  left: 70px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 10000;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
  .page-content{
   height:auto;
}
 #page-content-wrapper {
  width: 95%;
 height: auto;
 }
```

This is the Javascript. I put in the alert to see if its returning the correct position of where the attribute is. The alert works fine

```
<script>    
$('#sidebar a').click(function() {
var goTo = $($(this).attr('href')); // selects element that was clicked
var offset = goTo.offset(); //grabs position of element
alert(goTo.offset().top);
$('#page-content').animate({   
  scrollTop: $('#page-content-wrapper')[0].scrollTop + goTo.offset().top
}, 1000);
return false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(haven't tested) but should be

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $('#page-content-wrapper')[0].scrollTop.offset().top}, 1000);
```

**UPDATE**

Here you go, the problem was `overflow: auto` on the `body`. I cleaned up the JS to:[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/97pWg/)

Comment: tried.. didnt work... I had used the animate on html,body earlier too.directly jumping to anchor links without the animated scroll effect

Comment: can you post the rest of the HTML? This isn't displaying right in the fiddle